# AddMore button in RecyclerView is not removed

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a recyclerView with 2 ViewTypes: Images and 1 button. When I click that button I'm able to add one more image each time. I want that when I have 5 images, the button to disappear, without using `setView`(Gone). Here is my adapter, and I'm trying to remove the button in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
public class SelectPhotoAdapter  extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectPhotoHolder> {// Recyclerview will extend to
    // recyclerview adapter
    private ArrayList<Data_Model> arrayList;
    private Context context;

    private boolean hasLoadButton = true;
    private final int IMAGES = 0;
    private final int LOAD_MORE = 1;

    public SelectPhotoAdapter (Context context,
                                ArrayList<Data_Model> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;

    }


    public boolean itHasLoadButton() {
        return hasLoadButton;
    }

    public void setHasLoadButton(boolean hasLoadButton) {
        this.hasLoadButton = hasLoadButton;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (hasLoadButton) {
            return arrayList==null? 1 :arrayList.size() + 1;
        } else {
            return arrayList==null? 0 :arrayList.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position < getItemCount()-1) {
            return IMAGES;
        } else {
            return LOAD_MORE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SelectPhotoHolder holder, int position) {
        SelectPhotoHolder mainHolder = holder;// holder

        if(position >= getItemCount() -1) {
                mainHolder.addPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        arrayList.add(new Data_Model(SelectPhotoDialogFragment.IMAGES[0]));
                        SelectPhotoDialogFragment.adapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayList.size());
                        SelectPhotoDialogFragment.mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(arrayList.size());
                        Log.d("askj","Sizee: "+arrayList.size());
                        if(arrayList.size()>5&&itHasLoadButton()){
                            setHasLoadButton(false);
                            SelectPhotoDialogFragment.adapter.notifyItemRemoved(arrayList.size() + 1);
                            SelectPhotoDialogFragment.adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(arrayList.size() + 1, getItemCount());
                            Log.e("askj", "calledLoad");
                        }
                    }
                });
        } else {
            final Data_Model model = arrayList.get(position);
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    model.getImagePath());// This will convert drawbale image into
            mainHolder.imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
        }

    }




    @Override
    public SelectPhotoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == IMAGES) {

            return new SelectPhotoHolder((LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.selectphotolist, parent, false)),IMAGES);

        } else if (viewType == LOAD_MORE) {
            return new SelectPhotoHolder((LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.addphoto, parent, false)),LOAD_MORE);

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The method is called(I can see in the console 'calledLoad'), but the button is still there. I thought that by calling `setHasLoadButton`(false) the button will disappear, but it's not happening.

Let me know if I have to add more code.

Comment: I'm thinking you have some problems with `getItemViewType`. In particular I cannot see where you handle condition about 5 elements (probably in hasLoadButton, but it would be better to include its management inside adapter). Following your approach I tried to make another implementation. I've put code [here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/android-recycler-view/tree/alternative-list). Let me know if this could help.

Comment: Why do you think that ? It's doing what it is supposed to.

Comment: what I mean is that, since button is still there when you use it more than 4 times, problem could be related to how `getItemCount` and `getItemViewType` work in current implementation. Another possibility could be usage of notify methods. Did you tried to replace specific notification (e.g. item removed, inserted) with notifyDataSetChanged? Just for understanding if there could be any issue in using them. For example I see `SelectPhotoDialogFragment.adapter.notifyItemRemoved(arrayList.size() + 1)`, but if you are removing the button, position should be probably just `arrayList.size()`.

Comment: Try to change condition in `getItemViewType` from `position < getItemCount()-1` to `arrayList!=null && position < arrayList.size()`

Comment: doesn't make any difference. I'll just keep using `setView` until I find a solution

Comment: uhm... problem is that comparing position with `getItemCount()` will always keep a position for button as latest element. Comparing with `arrayList.size()` will ensure instead that only in case `hasLoadButton` is true, button is added at the end. With this modification your code works fine in my case. Maybe there's something else in your scenario.

Comment: where do you remove the button in your case ?

Comment: It is in some way automatic due to `hasLoadButton` variable. When it is true, an additional position is added with `getItemCount` and it is rendered as a button thanks to `getItemViewType`. In [repo](https://github.com/thetonrifles/android-recycler-view/tree/alternative-list) I've updated code for using your logic but with this modification applied. Hope this could help. In case we can continue in chat if you think I can better support you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102784/discussion-between-bogdan-daniel-and-thetonrifles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change condition in `getItemViewType` from `position < getItemCount()-1` to `arrayList!=null && position < arrayList.size()`.

Better also to move management of `OnClickListener` interface directly into `ViewHolder`.